# Displaying text on multiple lines in `react-tooltip`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tooltip

I use the library: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip`. I have a too long text, which is on one line, how can put it on multiple lines?

```
<p data-tip="hello world">Tooltip</p>
<ReactTooltip className="tooltip"/>

.tooltip {
  width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: use multiline:true property (or) html property available on the react-tool-tip - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-tooltip

Comment: @KannanG <ReactTooltip className="tooltip" multiline={true} /> but it doesn't work

Comment: <span data-tip='tooltip<br />multiline'></span>
<ReactTooltip multiline={true} />

Comment: try example like the above

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can use html={true} or multiline={true} both property to handle multiple line scenario

## html

```
var tooltiptest = 'this is <br /> a test';

<div data-tip={tooltiptest} data-for='path'>Path</div>

<ReactTooltip id='path' type='light' html={true} />
```

your example:

```
<p data-for='path' data-tip="hello <br /> world">Tooltip</p>
<ReactTooltip id='path' className="tooltip" html={true} />

.tooltip {
  width: 100px;
}
```

## multiline

```
<span data-tip='tooltip<br />multiline'></span>

<ReactTooltip multiline={true} />
```

your example

```
<p data-tip="hello <br /> world">Tooltip</p>
<ReactTooltip className="tooltip" multiline={true} />

.tooltip {
  width: 100px;
}
```

source - 
[reference1](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/217)
[reference2](https://github.com/wwayne/react-tooltip/issues/279)

## if you need to handle word-wrap for dynamic driven content, please follow the below style.

[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";

const styles = theme => ({
  overrideMe: {
    width: "100px",
    "word-break": "break-all",
    "overflow-wrap": "break-word",
    display: "block"
  }
});

class Opener extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      open: false
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <div>test content</div>
        <div>test content</div>
        <div>
          <p
            data-for="tt"
            data-tip="hello ccsdcssd csdccdsc ccdc sdcscds world"
          >
            Tooltip - hover me
          </p>
          <ReactTooltip
            className={classes["overrideMe"]}
            data-html={true}
            insecure={true}
            multiline={true}
            id="tt"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withStyles(styles)(Opener);
```

play with the code - [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-demo-reacttooltip-b8o89?fontsize=14)

Comment: I can't divide the text <br/> because I have the data returned by the Api server

Comment: actually in your case you dont know where to divide the line also right? i mean if server send you the big paragraph you dont know which place it get divided and how it get organized in UI? am i correct?

Comment: then you need to control the width of the <p> tag to handle the space and make the words wrap - refer - https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/docs/src/pages/components/tooltips/VariableWidth.js

Comment: I would prefer a react-tooltip not to install more libraries

Comment: understood, give me few min,  will work on it and give you solution, it seems we need to control the CSS of the tooltip to handle the word wrap

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: yes i tried it works, forgot to reply to you.. i am updating my answers now, please check

Comment: @Umbro please try and let me know

Answer (score 6):

If you style the component or html element, add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the css.

Answer (score 1):

BAD:

```
data-tooltip-content={tooltipContent}
```

GOOD. This respects multi-lines with HTML using the standard `<br/>`:

```
data-tooltip-html={tooltipContent}
```